# Kendo Grid - Edit mode when templated column is clicked

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using a template for the edit popup. I am trying to force the grid to go into edit mode and show the edit template popup when a link within one of the columns is clicked.

I tried using a command but I am unable to data bind the hyperlink's text to a field declared in the model, in this case to 'CourseType'. Is data binding supported within **command** columns?

```
columns: [
     { 
        command: [
          { 
            id: "edit", 
            title: "School Item",    
            template: '<a href="\\#">#=CourseType#</a>',  
            width: 120
          }
       ]
     }
]
```

If data binding is not supported within a command column, then how do I put the grid into edit mode when the templated field is clicked?

```
columns: [
  { 
    field: "CourseType", 
    title: "School Item",  
    template: '<a href="\\#">#=CourseType#</a>'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why do you want to define the cell as an HTML `anchor` but there is no problem on making it enter on popup edit mode when clicking on the anchor.

1) Add to your template a `class` that would allow us to find those cells. Something like:

```
columns: [
    {
        field: "CourseType",
        title: "School Item",
        template: '<a href="\\#" class="ob-edit-popup">#=CourseType#</a>'
    }
]
```

where I have include `class="ob-edit-popup"` to the template.

2) add to your grid definition the option `editable: "popup"`.

3) add the following JavaScript code after the initialization.

```
$(".ob-edit-popup", grid.tbody).on("click", function (e) {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    grid.editRow(row);
})
```

Where `grid` is the result of:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({...}).data("kendoGrid");
```